# select an array inside the perl script using $ARGV[]

Tags: perl

In my perl script I have multiple arrays and I have to decide which array to choose while executing the script using `$ARGV[]` and then that array I have to use in an `foreach` statement.

I have tried :

```
@array_1 = ("abc", "home", "city");
@array_2 = ("state", "planet", "stars");
foreach my $string ($ARGV[0]) {
    print "$string \n";
}
```

but this doesn't works as i need .

Comment: How would you choose one array or the other?

Comment: Perhaps put those arrays in another array, or a hash, to enable lookup. `for my $string (@{ $arrays[$ARGV[0]] }) `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using an array of arrays? Then you would enter a number for the array you want, e.g. `perl foo.pl 0` for array_1, and `1` for array_2.

```
use strict;
use warnings;   # always use these

my @array_1 = ("abc", "home", "city");
my @array_2 = ("state", "planet", "stars");
my @lookup = (\@array_1, \@array_2);
my @selected = @{ $lookup[$ARGV[0]] };
foreach my $string (@selected) {
    print "$string \n";
}
```

Or perhaps a hash? `perl foo.pl a1` for array_1.

```perl
my %lookup = ( a1 => [ "abc", "home", "city" ],
               a2 => [ "state", "planet", "stars" ]);
my @selected = @{ $lookup{$ARGV[0]} };
foreach my $string (@selected) {
    print "$string \n";
}
```

The hash solution makes sense if you have some valid categories, like for example:

```perl
my %lookup = (  fruit => [ qw(apple orange pear) ],
                cars  => [ qw(ford honda ferrarri) ],
                colours => [ qw(blue red yellow) ]);
```